# Partial view in Dotnet application not appearing

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5, partial-views, ef-core-5.0

I am having trouble with partial view in dotnet application i have been following Pro ASP.NET Core Identity book of Adam Freeman (Apress)

The Layout File look like the image below where i am calling partial view

[image]

and the partial view file looks like below

[image]

but the _Navigation Partial is not appearing in the app. The screenshot of runing app is below where at the top the partial view should appear and on click will redirect to the controller view page.

[image]